# Yii filter condition

Tags: sorting, yii

In my admin.php, I have a table and one of the columns is `Status` which gives only 2 options, `Open` or `Close`.

The below is in my admin.php

```
array(
                'name' => 'complete',
                'header'=>'Status',
                'value' => '($data->complete == 0) ? Yii::t(\'app\', \'Open\') : Yii::t(\'app\', \'Close\')',                   
                'filter' => array('0' => Yii::t('app', 'Open'), '1' => Yii::t('app', 'Close')),
),
```

I want it to show only the `Open` condition instead of everything. What can I add into the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show by default only the rows that are still open (not completed), you can simply go to the controller in the admin action and add:

```
$model->complete=0;
```

That should be placed just after defining the model and before assigning attributes from $_GET, so it can be overwritten if user choses other option.